# another way of saying "to photoshop an image"

Tags: synonyms

What is a different way of saying **to photoshop an image**?  I didn't use Photoshop.

Comment: manipulate, edit, amend...

Comment: Have you tried looking for a suitable term? Can you tell us what all you have found, so we could better help you?

Comment: Try "Edit digitally" and see if it fits your context. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris I was thinking about edit, filter, process, and enhance.  For the last word, enhance, it might not be the right word because sometime the resulting image is not better than the original one.

Comment: "Edit" in its broad sense covers all those (that apply in a case).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you did, you can use **retouch**.

> *retouch* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retouch))
>   verb [ T ]
>
> to make small changes to a picture, photograph, etc., especially in order to improve it:

Answer (score 0):

You can talk about ***manipulating*** an image, and [Adobe will thank you for doing so](https://www.adobe.com/legal/permissions/trademarks.html),

Comment: Thank you so much for the link.  I like the section `Trademarks must never be used as slang terms.` :)

Answer (score 0):

A google search for Photoshop synonyms  yields **photo-edit**.  It's a verb.